# How to determine if a camera resolution is available in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a function that allows the user to activate the camera. Now I want to give that user the option to select their chosen resolution. The problem is before I offer them the resolution how do I check to see if it is available.

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraUI.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

/// Different Options If Avalaible
cameraUI.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480;
cameraUI.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540;
cameraUI.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there a defined method to determine this behavior as of yet in the iOS SDK...

Two alternatives are using existing keys or using a conditional statement that checks current device.

**First alternative:** 
using the existing `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh, UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium and UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow` you can specify the quality without knowing exactly what it is. This allows the users to always have the best option were available

**Second alternative:** 
using conditional statement to check current device version and compare that to a hard-cored list of device with there camera resolution

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *) currentPlatform { // get current device
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);

    return platform;
}

// conditional statement 
NSString *device = [self currentPlatform];

if (device isEqualToString@"iPhone6,2") { // iPhone 5s 
    // return quality...
    // best bet is to look on Apple device spec and Wiki for deivce camera resolutions supported

}
```

For a full list of devices see this [glist](https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251)